# CHMOD owner/group 99 609

Tags: apache, unix, webserver, chmod

i user APACHE with PHP.
if we use FTP program like filezilla.
we will have field information about Permission (777) and Owner/Group (99 99)
in *NIX i understand how to translate the Permission like 777

- 4 = Read
- 2 = Write
- 1 = eXecute

where its mean RW = 42 = 6

but what about Owner/Group = 99 99

How to translate it??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are owner and group ids, so in the permission block :

- first number refers to owner rights (uid 99)
- second number refers to owner group rights (gid 99)
- third number refers to others rights

In your case, 777 is read/write/execute for owner, owner group, and others.

Comment: i still didn't understand. how we can know if 99 means root?

Comment: @GusDe Cool: actually root is always (*I think*) uid 0. Anyway, does it really matter as root is root ? =/ He can get through the permissions anyway